# How to exclude the update of an Xml Attribute by attribute name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

If I have an xml structure as:

```
 <TablixMembers>
      <TablixMember>
        <Group Name="Group1" />
      </TablixMember>
 </TablixMembers>
...
 <TablixMembers>
      <TablixMember>
        <Group Name="Group1" />
      </TablixMember>
 </TablixMembers>
...
 <TablixMembers>
      <TablixMember>
        <Group Name="Details" />
      </TablixMember>
 </TablixMembers>
...
```

The ellipse just represents other code in the document. I want to select all Group nodes except for the one Attributed as Details and change their value to some random guid.

I have tried the following

```
var groupName = from gn in report.Descendants(ns + "Group")
                                 where gn.Name != "Details"
                                 select gn;

    foreach (var name in groupName)
    {
       string randomName = GenerateUniqueName("Group");
       name.SetAttributeValue("Name",randomName);
    }
```

However when I run the code all node attributes end up getting updated with a random name. Would expect that the node `<Group Name="Details" />` would be excluded from the loop.

What am I missing in the select statement to exclude the Group node that contains `Name = "Deatils"`

-cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently looking for the name of the element - which will always be `Group` (in whatever namespace). That's what the `XNode.Name` property returns. You want to extract the *value* of the `Name` attribute:

```
var groupName = from gn in report.Descendants(ns + "Group")
                where (string) gn.Attribute("Name") != "Details"
                select gn;
```

Personally I wouldn't use a query expression for that though. I'd use:

```
var groupName = report.Descendants(ns + "Group")
                      .Where(gn => (string) gn.Attribute("Name") != "Details");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on attribute vs. node. And I agree on the query expression I just couldn't get it to work earlier as I was using Name and not Attribute.